# Increase speed in finding "Ιncreasing dice roll sequences"

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, purrr

The problem was *How many sequences of 9 dice rolls are increasing (e.g. 223444556)*. Ok, I know the answer is given by `choose(14,9)` but i just wanted to play around with dplyr.

A fast but not elegant way:

```
library(tidyverse)

expand.grid(data.frame(matrix(rep(1:6,9),ncol=9))) %>% 
 filter(X1<=X2 & X2<=X3 &X3<=X4 &X4<=X5 &X5<=X6 &X6<=X7 &X7<=X8 &X8<=X9) %>% tally
```

I tried the following two alternatives (without explicit reference to variable names), but they're both very slow (and memory consuming). Can you help me optimize my code using tidyverse?

```
 expand_grid(!!!data.frame(matrix(rep(1:6,9),ncol=9))) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "grp") %>% 
  mutate(grp = as.numeric(grp)) %>% 
  pivot_longer (cols=!grp) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  mutate(prev = lag(value)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(prev)) %>% 
  transmute(dif=value-prev) %>% 
  summarize(res = all(dif >=0)) %>% 
  group_by(res) %>% summarize(n=n())


 9 %>% 
    rerun(1:6) %>% crossing(!!!.,.name_repair = "minimal") %>%
    set_names(glue::glue('c{1:ncol(.)}')) %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(asc = all(diff(c_across(cols = everything())>=0))) %>% 
    filter(asc==TRUE) %>% tally
```

This is also slow, but not memory consuming.

```
 9 %>% 
  rerun(1:6) %>% crossing(!!!.,.name_repair = "minimal")  %>% 
  set_names(glue::glue('c{1:ncol(.)}')) %>% 
  filter(pmap_lgl(.,~{
    if(all(list(...) %>% flatten_dbl() %>% diff() >=0)) return(TRUE) else return(FALSE)
  })) %>% tally
```

Comment: How do you know the answer is `choose(14, 9)`? Could you lead me towards documentation / background on the subject?

Comment: @Cole Oh, it' s just the number of combinations of 6 objects taken 9 at a time _with
repetitions_. e.g. [link](https://sites.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/courses/cs310-05s/notes/dm-gcomb#:~:text=Two%20combinations%20with%20repetition%20are,at%20a%20time%20with%20repetition.) This is also equal to the number of ways 9 identical objects can be distributed among 6 distinct containers - solved easily using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two_2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach that relies on `purrr`:

```r
expand.grid(replicate(9, 1:6, FALSE)) %>%
  filter(reduce(map2(.[, -length(.)], .[, -1], ~ .x <= .y), `&`)) %>%
  tally()
```

This is somewhat difficult to do in the contexts of pipes. We both need to compare columns `n` and `n + 1` while reducing done to a logical vector. Then we need to filter the original dataset.

And if you were *only* interested in the tally, we could sum the logical vector.

```
expand.grid(replicate(9, 1:6, FALSE)) %>%
  {sum(reduce(map2(.[, -length(.)], .[, -1], ~ .x <= .y), `&`))}
```

Finally, if you don't mind one more dependency, [matrixstats](/questions/tagged/matrixstats) can parallel what you were doing with one of your approaches:

```r
library(matrixStats)

expand.grid(replicate(9, 1:6, FALSE)) %>%
  {sum(rowAlls(rowDiffs(as.matrix(.)) >= 0L))}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another, more efficient solution, which uses a custom function `get_nondecreasing_seqs`, but does not use the tidyverse or dplyr.

```
get_nondecreasing_seqs <- function(digits, current_vector = numeric(0), allowed_nums) {
  res <- list()
  
  move_to_next <- function(new_digit, current_vector) {
    # Check if you have reached the desired length
    if (length(current_vector) == digits) {
      res[length(res) + 1] <<- list(current_vector)
    } else {
      # Try appending each allowed digit to the current vector
      for (next_digit in allowed_nums[allowed_nums >= new_digit]) {
        # Recursively call the function with the updated vector
        move_to_next(next_digit, c(current_vector, next_digit))
      }
    }
  }
  
  move_to_next(1, current_vector)
  
  return(res)
}

get_nondecreasing_seqs(9, allowed_nums = 1:6)
```

In the original approach using expand.grid and the tidyverse, all possible combinations of dice rolls were generated first, and then the non-decreasing sequences were filtered. This method could lead to a substantial memory overhead, especially when dealing with a large number of dice rolls, as it creates all combinations upfront.

In contrast, the custom function `get_nondecreasing_seqs` takes a more optimized approach. It dynamically builds the sequences while avoiding unnecessary combinations. It starts with the first digit and recursively explores only those paths that lead to non-decreasing sequences. This significantly reduces the number of iterations and memory usage, especially when the sequence length is large.

The efficiency gain comes from the fact that the function explores and appends valid digits to the current vector on the fly, eliminating the need to generate and store all possible combinations beforehand. This makes the custom function more resource-efficient and faster for calculating the non-decreasing sequences of dice rolls.

Comment: IMHO, if you added some benchmark tests to quantify the improvement in speed your method provides over other approaches, this would be a stronger answer than it is at the moment.

Comment: Excellent, and yes, it boosted the speed remarkably! +1! See my benchmark result.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a recursion to make it, which should be much faster than `expand.grid`

```
f1 <- function(k, v = 1:6) {
    if (k == 1) {
        return(as.list(v))
    }
    unlist(
        lapply(
            Recall(k - 1),
            \(x) lapply(v[v >= x[k-1]], \(p) c(x, p))
        ),
        recursive = FALSE
    )
}

f2 <- function(k, v = 1:6) {
    expand.grid(replicate(k, v, FALSE)) %>%
        {
            sum(reduce(map2(.[, -length(.)], .[, -1], ~ .x <= .y), `&`))
        }
}

f3 <- function(digits, current_vector = numeric(0), allowed_nums= 1:6) {
    res <- list()

    move_to_next <- function(new_digit, current_vector) {
        # Check if you have reached the desired length
        if (length(current_vector) == digits) {
            res[length(res) + 1] <<- list(current_vector)
        } else {
            # Try appending each allowed digit to the current vector
            for (next_digit in allowed_nums[allowed_nums >= new_digit]) {
                # Recursively call the function with the updated vector
                move_to_next(next_digit, c(current_vector, next_digit))
            }
        }
    }

    move_to_next(1, current_vector)

    return(res)
}

microbenchmark(
    TIC = f1(9),
    Cole = f2(9),
    Brani = f3(9),
    unit = "relative",
    times = 10L
)
```

and you will see that

```
Unit: relative
  expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval
   TIC   1.649896   1.652466   1.513901   1.648688   1.489092  1.497073    10
  Cole 148.716366 158.463960 128.162563 148.872885 134.907332 78.664232    10
 Brani   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000  1.000000    10
```

and the output `out <- f1(9)` looks like

```
> out <- f1(9)

> length(out)
[1] 2002

> head(out)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3

[[4]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4

[[5]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 5

[[6]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the package: **RcppAlgos**
It's very fast! (powered by C++)

```
library(RcppAlgos)

dice=9; die=1:6
ma <- comboGeneral(die, dice, repetition = TRUE)   
dim(ma)
#[1] 2002    9
```

Comment: @Brani:  #Convert list to matrix: dice=9; die=1:6; res <- get_nondecreasing_seqs(dice, allowed_nums = die); ma <- matrix(as.integer(unlist(res)), ncol=dice, byrow =TRUE); dim(ma)

Answer (score 1):

```
n <- 9
success <- 0

throw <- function(last_throw = 1, hist = "") {
  if (nchar(hist) == n)  {
    success <<- success + 1L
    return(NULL)
  }
  for (i in last_throw:6) throw(last_throw = i, hist = paste0(hist, i)) 
}
throw()
success
# [1] 2002
```

Simplified:

```
throw <- function(last_throw = 1L, len = 0L) {
  if (len == n)  {
    success <<- success + 1L
    return(NULL)
  }
  for (i in last_throw:6L) throw(last_throw = i, len = len + 1L) 
}
throw()
success
# [1] 2002
```

Comment: nice, this gives fast computation of the cardinality of valid sequences, +1!